# If I am reducing the size of a char ** pointer using realloc, does it internally frees up the individual char * pointers of the reduction size

Tags: c

I am trying to reduce the size of a `char **` double pointer using `realloc`.
First the `char **` pointer is allocated using `malloc` and then the individual `char*`  pointers as given below.

```
    char **first= (char**)malloc(num*sizeof(char*)); 
    char **last=(char**)malloc(num*sizeof(char*));

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    //each individual pointer holds 20 characters
            first[i]=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char)); 
            last[i]=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));

    }
```

Now after some operations, I want to reduce the size of first and last by one counter value where counter is less than `num`.
Purpose is to free last counter number of records.

If I do the following

```
//Freeing up internal pointer memories
        i = 0;
        while (i<counter)
        {
            free(first[num1-1 - i]);
            free(last[num1-1-i]);
            i++;
         }

    //Reducing the size of the double pointer using realloc
      first = (char **)realloc(first, (num1-counter) * sizeof(char *));
      last = (char **)realloc(last, (num1-counter) * sizeof(char *) );
```

After this if I print the records

```
    for(i=0; i<num - counter; i++){
         printf("First Name: %s ",first[i]);
         printf("Last Name: %s ",last[i]);
    }`
```

The last record seems to be corrupted.

If I just perform the following and do not free the individual `char *` pointers, it works fine.

```
first = (char **)realloc(first, (num1-counter) * sizeof(char *));
last = (char **)realloc(last, (num1-counter) * sizeof(char *) );
```

My question is does `realloc` of a double pointer to reduce the size, internally frees up the internal pointers and as I am doing both, it is some how corrupting the memory?

Comment: You are using the right technique. It sounds like there is a bug in your code elsewhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [don't cast malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Allocations done with `num`, `free()` done with `num1`.  Re-allocations done with `num1`.  Printing done with `num` -->  Hmmm?

Comment: "My question is does `realloc` of a double pointer to reduce the size, internally frees up the internal pointers" --> No.  `realloc()` does not know there are pointers.  Problem is in un-posted code.

Comment: You don't reduce the size of the pointer, but what it points to! And **always** check the result of `realloc`, `malloc` & friends for errors! For `realloc` you must not overwrite the original pointer before you ensured the call succeeded!

Comment: But you can reduce the number of allocated pointers by passing the exact **count** you need and resizing to that number using `realloc`. If count is less than the currently allocated number of pointers, space for the excess pointers will be freed (released) from the current allocation.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No, it doesn't.

Freeing the nested pointers in a `char **` might be rude if the pointer is still in use somewhere else.

The C compiler doesn't follow memory pointers around, nor does it count object references, so it's up to you to `free` (or keep) the allocated memory of the nested strings within the `char **`.

As for the example code itself, it seems to have issues, but these were described in the comments to your question.